# How should the "CDPATH" command be written in the .bashrc file?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, terminal, shortcut

I have a directory deep in folders (XAMPP) I'd like to `cd` into directly into.

I run this in the terminal: `CDPATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/`
And it works!

So if I want this to be permanent, I must add this same line to the `.bashrc` file. But adding the same line to my `.bashrc` file doesn't work.

My `.bashrc` file contains:

```
[ -n "$PS1" ] && source ~/.bash_profile
CDPATH=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/
```

How should the line look like in the `.bashrc` file? Is mines wrong? I've tried putting `export` in front of `CDPATH` and also `$CDPATH:${HOME}/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs` but neither works.

Comment: `CDPATH` is a variable, not a command.

Comment: Where is the variable defined?

Comment: Try to set it from the command line first, get it working there, then add it to your login scripts.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First be aware that CDPATH is considered first, hence you will not be able to easily change to a local directory if the other directory contains a directory with the same name. You will probably add an empty path in front, writing `CDPATH=:/Application/...`.

You should not need the `export` as this one is only relevant for you shell, not for commands run by your shell. The line as you wrote it should be fine.

Be aware that, depending how you start it, bash will read `~/.bashrc` or `~/.bash_profile`. Add an `echo` line in both to debug which file is evaluated in your context.

Comment: Hmm in `/Application` there is only one folder called `XAMPP`. However in `htdocs` there's also a folder called `xampp` (lowercase).

Would that be the root if the issue? I've tried `CDPATH=/Applications/../XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/localweb/` 
And a few 'empty path' variations with no success.

Comment: For now, the exact content of `CDPATH` is of no matter. The question is, whether it is set at all. You can check with `echo $CDPATH` for example. - It is probably not set. Therefore you have to find out why. - I assume it is because your shell is started as a login shell and therefore does **not** read your `.bashrc`.

Comment: Looks like `echo $CDPATH` returns the root directory `~`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want directly go to `htdocs` with `cd htdocs`, you should enter:

```
export CDPATH=:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles
```

to your `$HOME/.profile` (and open new Terminal.app window - or `source $HOME/.profile`)

after this, the

```
cd htdocs
```

will cd to `/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs`

you can also make special alias for it, e.g.:

```
alias xcd="cd /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs"
```

Comment: I tried putting both of those lines in `~/.profile` but still no success. I assume `~` is my `$HOME`?

Comment: I have `export CDPATH=:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/` in my .profile in my `~` directory. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @HenryZhu YES - read my answer CAREFULLY! You should have `CDPATH=:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles` and NOT `PATH=:/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/`

Comment: None of the instruction work. Tried it in .profile, .bash_profile and .bashrc.